# How to grep or search 3 word Patterns in a file and print them along with the content between second and third word Pattern

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, perl

How to find or search word PATTERN1 and PATTERN2 and print them both later i want to search PATTERN3 and Print the whole content or section between the search PATTERN2/PATTERN3 
(Note Pattern1/2/3 occurs many time within the file)

Input file

```
other lines
...
####Pattern 1####
...
other lines
...
####Pattern 2####
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line ...
####Pattern 3####
...
other lines
####Pattern 1####
...
other lines
####Pattern 2####
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
####Pattern 3####
...
other lines
```

Output l need is

```
####Pattern 1####
####Pattern 2####
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4...etc
####Pattern 3####
```

Comment: If PATTERN1 occurs between PATTERN2 and PATTERN3, does PATTERN1 get printed twice?  I think not but the specification is not clear, and this case is not in the example.

Comment: It's impossible to generate the example output from the example input because this data: "line 4...etc" is nonexistent in the input.  Please show the actual output that you need, without annotations in the data.

Comment: Hi RobertL and DouglasDD, 
If Pattern1 exist between Pattern2/3 it shouldn't get printed
Also if Pattern3 comes between Pattern1/2 it should not print. 

So the search  should be like it should search Pattern1 first then Pattern2 and Pattern 3 and then print it out.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand your specification.  Can you update your example to cover all of these cases?

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've specified that we need to skip all the spurious patterns that can appear out of the expected order, we require something more complicated like a finite state machine.

So here's a much more complicated sample input file that includes all the weird edge cases, and comments:

```
a
#### Pattern 2 #### Ignore because we have not yet seen Pattern 1
z
#### Pattern 3 #### Ignore because we have not yet seen Pattern 1, 2
b
#### Pattern 1 #### (!!)
#### Pattern 1 #### Don't print 1 in between 1-2
c
d
#### Pattern 2 #### (!!)
e
#### Pattern 1 #### Don't print 1 in between 2-3
#### Pattern 2 #### ?? Don't print 2 in between 2-3 ??
f
#### Pattern 3 #### (!!)
?? Now reset and accept look for the start of a NEW 1,2,3 cycle. Right ??
g
#### Pattern 3 #### Ignore
#### Pattern 2 #### Ignore
#### Pattern 3 #### Ignore
h
#### Pattern 1 #### (!!)
i
#### Pattern 3 #### Don't print 3 in between 1-2
j
#### Pattern 2 #### (!!)
k
l
#### Pattern 3 #### (!!)
m
n
```

Expected output:

```
#### Pattern 1 #### (!!)
#### Pattern 2 #### (!!)
e
f
#### Pattern 3 #### (!!)
#### Pattern 1 #### (!!)
#### Pattern 2 #### (!!)
k
l
#### Pattern 3 #### (!!)
```

So it looks like we need to buid a finite state machine with 3 states. So now we're writting a full fledged script....

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

## Linear state machine 0 --> 1 --> 2 --> 0
my @patterns = (
    qr(Pattern 1),  # state 0: noprint;              match this: noprint && state = 1
    qr(Pattern 2),  # state 1: noprint;              match this:   print && state = 2
    qr(Pattern 3)   # state 2: print (NOT patterns); match this: print   && stage = 0
    );
my $state = 0;

while (<>) {
    if (0 == $state) {
        if (m/$patterns[0]/) {
            ++$state;
        }
    } elsif (1 == $state) {
        if (m/$patterns[1]/) {
            print;
            ++$state;
        }
    } elsif (2 == $state) {
        if (m/$patterns[0]/ || m/$patterns[1]/) {
            # Ignore
        } elsif (m/$patterns[2]/) {
            print;
            $state = 0;
        } else {
            print;
        }
    } else {
        die "Bad programmer! ($state)";
    }
}
```

Kinda ugly.  A more flexible state machine could be implemented with a hash of
`[$state_num, $pattern_num] => sub { ...action... }`
where skip/ignore is the default action for any [state, pattern] combination that doesn't appear in the hash.  But that's left as an exercise to the enthusiastic reader ;-)

Comment: Hi DouglasDD, 
If Pattern1 exist between Pattern2/3 it shouldn't get printed
Also if Pattern3 comes between Pattern1/2 it should not print. 

So the search  should be it should search Pattern1 first then Pattern2 and 3 and then print it out.

Comment: The above Perl you shared does do the job but there are Pattern 3 in between Pattern 1/ 2 which should not get printed. in your case it does get printed which is not needed

Comment: Hi Douglas in the above sample from you and the output,
This is wrong as after Pattern2 Pattern 1 is coming So this output is not expected
#### Pattern 1 #### (!!)
#### Pattern 2 #### (!!)
e
f
#### Pattern 3 #### (!!)


Print should happened only if the sequence is found from Pattern1/2/3

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting more confused not less!  We're really going to need a complete example full of edge cases, and the correct output.  What's confusing me now is when which other patterns can be ignored, f/ex:  """In mode 'looking for 3 how do we handle 2? 1?"""  And the same for all 9 possible combinations of `in mode $x and found pattern $y` (for $x in 1..3 and $y in 1..3).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward with sed:

```
sed -n '/Pattern 1/p; /Pattern 2/,/Pattern 3/p' file
```

```
####Pattern 1####
####Pattern 2####
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line ...
####Pattern 3####
####Pattern 1####
####Pattern 2####
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
####Pattern 3####
```

---

Given Douglas's input file, we can have this awk that produces his expected output. Like his answer, this is a state machine that uses a couple of logical variables to determine the state:

```
awk -v p1="#### Pattern 1 ####" \
    -v p2="#### Pattern 2 ####" \
    -v p3="#### Pattern 3 ####" '
        $0 ~ p1 && !have_p1 && !in_p2p3             {have_p1 = $0}
        $0 ~ p2 &&  have_p1 && !in_p2p3             {in_p2p3 = 1; print have_p1; print}
        have_p1 &&  in_p2p3 && $0 !~ p1 && $0 !~ p2 {print}
        $0 ~ p3 &&  in_p2p3                         {in_p2p3 = 0; have_p1 = ""}
' file
```

```
#### Pattern 1 #### (!!)
#### Pattern 2 #### (!!)
e
f
#### Pattern 3 #### (!!)
#### Pattern 1 #### (!!)
#### Pattern 2 #### (!!)
k
l
#### Pattern 3 #### (!!)
```

Comment: Hi Glenn, it works fine but if Pattern 1 is not there it shouldn't print the next Pattern2/3, In your case it does prints them

Comment: Why is this requirement not in your question?

Comment: I see other comments as well. You need to give us sample input that can encapsulate **all** your requirements and edge cases.

Comment: Sorry My bad couldnt capture the cases inthe sample, anyway in the above comments Dogulas has captured the sample the output which is what i want, if that can be done in a more simple way in sed would be of great help to me

Comment: I feel confident saying this cannot be done *in a simple way* with sed

Comment: Is there any other better way other than the one Douglas mentioned like any simpler way to do with bash command

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this , which goes over the input file twice. First time it goes over and looks at the pattern lines only and from these we determine the state transitions and note the required : 1->2->3.

```
code=$(< INPUT_FILE \
    sed -e '/Pattern [1-3]/!d;=' |\
    sed -e 'N;s/\n/:/'                     |\
    sed -e '
        /Pattern 1/!d;$d;N
        /\n.*Pattern 1/D
        /Pattern 2/!d;$d;N
        /Pattern 3/!d
    '                                      |\
    sed -e '
        s/:.*//;N;s///;N;s///
        s/\n.*\n/,/;s/$/p/
    '
)

# and having computed the right ranges to print, we now enter the 2nd pass
sed -ne "$code" inp |\
sed -e '/Pattern 1/,/Pattern 2/!b' -e '//!d'
```

and if you want just one invocation of `sed` , you can do that too as shown below:

```
sed -e '
    /Pattern 1/,/Pattern 2/!d    ;# reject non-interesting range
    /Pattern 1/h                 ;# store in hold beginning of range
    /Pattern [23]/H              ;# store pattern 2 and 3 lines in hold too
    /Pattern 2/!d                ;# not at end of range ... delete
    g;/Pattern 3/d               ;# range seen completed, now check whether pattern 3 came
                                 ;# during the 1->2 search, and delete everything & restart
                                 ;# afresh if it did. otherwise, empty the pattern space in
                                 ;# preparation for reading the 2->3
    s/.*//

    :loop                        ;# setup a while(1) loop to read 2->3 range
        $d;N                     ;# read the next line into the pattern space provided
                                 ;# it isnt the last
        /Pattern [12]/d          ;# if we encounter pattern 1/2 then drop everything & start afresh
        /Pattern 3/{             ;# we checked 1/2 didnot come and 3 came
            s/^\n//;H;g;b
        }
    bloop
' input-file.txt
```

Here is the FSM-based approach using `hashes` to encode the present-state,next-state relation ship (Mealy-machine formulation):

```
perl -lne '
    BEGIN {
        sub getLinetype {
            local $_ = @_ ? shift : $_;
            return
                /Pattern 1/ ? "PATT_1" :
                /Pattern 2/ ? "PATT_2" :
                /Pattern 3/ ? "PATT_3" :
                "NON_PATT_123";
        }

        # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        #     PS      line_type             NS             action
        # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        $h{ RESET  }{ PATT_1       } = [ "STATE1", sub { @A = ( $_ ) } ];
        $h{ RESET  }{ PATT_2       } = [ "RESET",  sub { @A = ()     } ];
        $h{ RESET  }{ PATT_3       } = [ "RESET",  sub { @A = ()     } ];
        $h{ RESET  }{ NON_PATT_123 } = [ "RESET",  sub { @A = ()     } ];
        # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        $h{ STATE1 }{ PATT_1       } = [ "STATE1", sub { @A = ( $_ ) } ];
        $h{ STATE1 }{ PATT_2       } = [ "STATE2", sub { push @A, $_ } ];
        $h{ STATE1 }{ PATT_3       } = [ "RESET",  sub { @A = ()     } ];
        $h{ STATE1 }{ NON_PATT_123 } = [ "STATE1", sub {     ;       } ];
        # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        $h{ STATE2 }{ PATT_1       } = [ "STATE1", sub { @A = ( $_ ) } ];
        $h{ STATE2 }{ PATT_2       } = [ "RESET",  sub { @A = ()     } ];
        $h{ STATE2 }{ PATT_3       } = [ "STATE3", sub { print for splice(@A), $_ } ];
        $h{ STATE2 }{ NON_PATT_123 } = [ "STATE2", sub { push @A, $_ } ];
        # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        $h{ STATE3 }{ PATT_1       } = [ "STATE1", sub { @A = ( $_ ) } ];
        $h{ STATE3 }{ PATT_2       } = [ "RESET",  sub { @A = ()     } ];
        $h{ STATE3 }{ PATT_3       } = [ "RESET",  sub { @A = ()     } ];
        $h{ STATE3 }{ NON_PATT_123 } = [ "RESET",  sub { @A = ()     } ];
        # ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        $present_state = "RESET";
    }

    my $line_type = getLinetype();

    my $next_state = $h{$present_state}{$line_type}->[0];
    my $action_ref = $h{$present_state}{$line_type}->[1];

    $action_ref->();

    $present_state = $next_state;
' input-file.txt
```